# Invoke servlet Filters from another servlet

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, requestdispatcher

I'm working on a CMS.

My code is inside the `doGet()` function of a servlet invoked at url `"/market"`. I want a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` that would pass through all filters set for url `"/page"`.

I expect these filters would update the request, so that an annotation processor could later inject dependencies with correct values.

I'm in a Tomcat server, so I should be able to cast to the right special object, and I don't have to be compliant to other servers.

An associated question is that  using `req.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);`, I was expecting the filters to be invoked. Should they ?
The javadoc says:

> This method allows one servlet to do preliminary processing of a
>   request

Answer (score 1):

Filters are by default mapped on the `REQUEST` dispatcher only. The below example of a filter mapping

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

is implicitly equivalent to

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This means, the filter is only triggered on the "raw" incoming request, not on a forwarded request.

There are three more dispatchers: `FORWARD`, `INCLUDE` and `ERROR`. The [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-) triggers the `FORWARD` dispatcher. If you'd like to let your filter hook on that as well, then just add it:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Note that you need to explicitly specify the `REQUEST` dispatcher here, otherwise it would assume that you're overriding it altogether and are only interested in `FORWARD` dispatcher.

Inside the filter, if you'd like to distinguish between a `REQUEST` and `FORWARD`, then you can then check that by determining the presence of a request attribute keyed with [`RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)

```
String forwardRequestURI = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);

if (forwardRequestURI != null) {
    // Forward was triggered on the given URI.
}
```